# what function is err_dump()?

Tags: c

unix-stream-client.c

```
#include "unix.h"

int main(void)
{
        int sockfd, servlen;
        struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;

        if ((sockfd= socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
                err_dump("client: can't open stream socket");

        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, servlen) < 0)
                err_dump("client: can't connect to server");

        str_cli(stdin, sockfd);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
}
```

and when I gcc -c unix-stream-client.c , this file give this error: implicit declaration of function 'err_dump' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
err_dump("client: can't open stream socket");

and I don't understand why is giving me this error

Comment: "Implicit declaration" means that the compiler cannot find a definition for the function `err_dump()`. You need to ensure that you have included a header file which declares that function and link with a library which implements it, _or_ declare `err_dump()` as `extern` and compile a file which implements it on the same command line as this `unix-stream-client.c`.

Comment: `err_dump()` is not a standard C or Unix function. And `unix.h` is not a standard header file.

Comment: regardinng: `int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,
                   socklen_t addrlen);`  the last parameter of this function is expected to be an `unsigned` (socklen_t) not an `int`

Comment: the `c99` is a over 20 year obsolete standard.  Suggest using a much later version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is actually from the book ***`UNIX Network Programming The Sockets Networking`***

```
void
err_dump(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, LOG_ERR, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    abort(); /* dump core and terminate */
    exit(1); /* shouldn't get here */
}
```

and

```
static void
err_doit(int errnoflag, int level, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    int errno_save, n;
    char buf[MAXLINE + 1];
    errno_save = errno; /* value caller might want printed */

    #ifdef HAVE_VSNPRINTF
    vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE, fmt, ap); * safe */
    #else
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, ap); /* not safe */
    #endif
    n = strlen(buf);
    if (errnoflag)
    snprintf(buf + n, MAXLINE - n, ": %s", strerror(errno_save));
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    if (daemon_proc) {
        syslog(level, buf);
    } else {
        fflush(stdout); /* in case stdout and stderr are the same */
        fputs(buf, stderr);
        fflush(stderr);
    }
    return;
}
```

The code you try to compile was written by someone who was learning from this book.

Not a very good functions. The author loves `void` functions and forgot that some return useful values. Instead he prefers to use `strlen`.

Comment: I wouldn't blame the author. Consider the book's age and the comment [`Sigh, some vsprintf's return ptr, not length`](https://github.com/milley/unpv22e/blob/master/lib/snprintf.c#L21) in a different file.

Comment: @cremno link to some not conforming version of function does not proof anything. What this function **has** to return is defined in the C standard. I can write `strlen` returning length with all bits negated. And then write *Sigh, some `strlen`'s do not return  length*

Comment: It proofs the author wanted or had to support implementations which weren't compliant when the book/example code was originally written. Obviously it's bad code nowadays.